# Why do I get error expected ';' before ')' token?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

When I try to compile this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

unsigned long long int V[100000000], Sum[100000000];

int main()
{

   ifstream fin("stergeri.in");
   ofstream fout("stergeri.out");
   int N, i, nrPrel, aux=0, poz1, poz2, pasi=0, Ninit, deScos, poz, p=0;


   fin >> N;

   for(i=1; i<=N; i++) {
       fin >> V[i];
   };

   for(N>1){
       for(i=1; i<=N; i++) {
       nrPrel = V[i];
       while(nrPrel>0){
           aux = aux + nrPrel % 10;
           nrPrel = nrPrel / 10;
           Sum[i] = aux;
   }
       aux=0;
}


   for(i=1;i<=N-1;i++)
   {
       if(Sum[i]>Sum[i+1]){
           poz1=i;
           break;
       } else if (Sum[i+1]>Sum[i]) {
           poz1=i+1;
       }
   }

       for(i=poz1+1;i<=N-1;i++)
   {
       if(Sum[i]>Sum[i+1]){
           poz2=i;
           break;
       } else if (Sum[i+1]>Sum[i]) {
           poz2=i+1;
       }
   }


       for(i=poz2+1;i<=N-1;i++)
   {
       if(Sum[i]>Sum[i+1]){
           poz2=i;
           break;
       } else if (Sum[i+1]>Sum[i]) {
           poz2=i+1;
       }
   }

   aux=0;
   aux=poz2-poz1;
   deScos=aux+1;
   Ninit=N;
   N=N-aux;
   poz=Ninit;

   for(i=0; i<=deScos; i++) {
       aux=0;
       aux=V[poz];
       V[poz1+p]=V[poz];
       V[poz1+p]=aux;
       poz++;
       p++;
   }

   }


       for(i=0; i<=Ninit; i++) {
           fout << V[i] << " ";
   }

}
```

It tells me this:

> main.cpp|22|error: expected ';' before ')' token|

It refers to

> for(N>1){....}
> But if I put a **;**
> for(N>1;){....}
> , it tells me

> main.cpp|22|error: expected primary-expression before ')' token|

So, I see that it

What can I do?
I really need help...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Remove ";" after closing brace of for, also for(N>1) is not valid in c++. replace it by while(N>1)

Comment: If your indentation is correct your int main() ends before `for(i=1;i<=N-1;i++)`

Answer (score 1):

```
for(n>1)
```

is not correct format/syntax, it should be written similar to your other statement

```
for(i=1;i<=N-1;i++)
```

Also, you don't need a semicolon on your statement:

```
for(i=1; i<=N; i++) {
       fin >> V[i];
   };
```

It should be

```
for(i=1; i<=N; i++) {
       fin >> V[i];
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

A `for` loop has three clauses (separated by `;`): an initializer, then a condition, then an update step.  Your `for (N>1) {...}` is invalid because it only has one clause.

If you want to omit any of those clauses, you may (by leaving them blank, but still using `;` to separate those blank clauses). For example, it is valid to have a `for` loop that only checks its condition:

```
for ( ; N>1; ) {...}
```

However, if that is what you had wanted, then you might as well have done `while (N>1) {...}`.